# Embed Excel VBA script in Powershell Script

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I wrote a Powershell script that queries all of my groups from Exchange Online, then gets membership for each of those groups and saves each group to a separate CSV file. This is all working fine.
(Some non relevant parts omitted for brevity):

```
$excelTemplate = "$($fileLocation)\group-breakout.xlsm"
Copy-Item $excelTemplate "$($tempPath)\group-breakout-$($curDate).xlsm"

# Creating Excel COM Object
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excelFile = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\group-breakout -Include *.xlsm -Recurse

# Gathering all groups:
Write-Host "Getting all groups from Exchange Online..."
$allGroups = Get-DistributionGroup | select Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, ManagedBy, MemberJoinRestriction 
$allGroups | Export-Csv "$($tempPath)\1-AllGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "`tDone."
# Gathering members for all groups
Write-Host "Getting members for all groups from Exchange Online..."
$allGroups | ForEach-Object {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Name | select DisplayName, Alias, PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-Csv "$($tempPath)\$($_.name.Replace("/","-")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
Write-Host "`tDone."

# Calling macro in xlsm to merge the created csvs into a Excel spreadsheet
Write-Host "Creating Spreadsheet..."
        $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelFile) # Opening workbook
        $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1) # Selecting worksheet
        $excel.Run("ImportCSVs") # Calling macro
        $workbook.save() #Saving workbook
        $workbook.close() # Closing workbook
$excel.quit() # Closing Excel COM Object
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null # Making sure Excel process is closed.
```

I also have an Excel VBA script access through a COM object that will take those CSVs and add them to an XLSX with each CSV being one worksheet:

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = "C:\temp\group-breakout\"                  'path to CSV files, include the final \
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'no error messages, take default answers
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                    'open a CSV file
        wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete                       'delete sheet if it exists
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)    'move new sheet into Mstr
        Columns.AutoFit             'clean up display
        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
    Loop

Worksheets("1-AllGroups").Activate
Worksheets("placeholder").Delete
Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\group-breakout\group-breakout.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

The issue I have is having to include the Excel macro-enabled spreadsheet in the script location so I can access it from the script. Is there a way to somehow embed the VBA script in the Powershell script and run it inside of Excel? Or, alternatively, a way to perform the tasks in the VBA script using Powershell directly?

Comment: I found a similar question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486939/vba-and-powershell-integration