# VBA and PowerShell integration?

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am trying to create, one, a macro, that when data is entered into a cell range, it will trigger a PowerShell script. Within this PowerShell script, I am trying to get the objects from my PowerShell query to return back to the active worksheet, where the macro was triggered. The only hard part is, the Workbook is on a SharePoint server.

Does anyone have any insight of how to accomplish my goal, or any links to help point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a change event so you can handle checking when the data in the cell has changed.

Secondly you need a method returning data from a powershell command. I simply use the >> operator from a command line operation to put the data into a text file and then read the text file later.

Thirdly you need to do something with that data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then ' If A1 changes...
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim DataLine As String
    Dim objShell
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    FileName = "C:\data.txt"
    cmdString = "Powershell DIR >>" + FileName ' Cmd String for Powershell
    Call objShell.Run(cmdString, 0, True) ' Run the command, data is exported to FileName path

    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum ' Open the File we generated
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        ' Do something with data line that was saved from the shell script.
    Wend
    Close #FileNum
    Call fso.DeleteFile(FileName) ' Delete the file we generated
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much, I truly appreciate it the insight.