# Open external application from access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been looking online how to open an application through Access using VBA. I have since found the below example code, that does work:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "J:\Prepay\GE Debt logger.accdb"
```

I have resolved my problem, but I did notice that whilst trying to find my answer, most advice online suggested the below method or something similar:

```
Shell "Z:\DATA\METRO\ComTool\Update\Update.mdb"
```

My questions is, the methods I was finding online involved modules, or the use of shell, I wonder why? Why not just use the .followhyperlink, is there a reason not to?

Comment: Hi dmorgan 20, I have answered a similar problem with how to use powershell from VBA, which should also be able to execute any file (not just run powershell). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486939/vba-and-powershell-integration/35487436#35487436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell function doesn't work only with executables. 
I tried it with MSAcesss 2010 and it not worked.

FollowHyperlink is working, but start an executable with a security question.